Use MathJax / $\TeX$ within Cryptography META
The main site of Cryptography uses MathJax extensively. I would like to have the same thing enabled on Meta.
I can think of the following reasons to do so:

it is more consistent with the main site;
it allows copying (parts of) questions and answers here for discussion (do we need questions like these);
it allows us to answer specific questions on MathJax / Tex related to cryptography.

There is of course the drawback of bandwidth, but with the current amount of articles posted on meta, this should not be much of an issue. I don't think it will matter with regards to readability / client support either - if you cannot read Cryptography then there is no reason to be on Meta in the first place.
I'm also planning to make a Wiki-like post on the common TeX constructs used on Meta, which is kind of impossible without MathJax support. The TeX site is nice but often you find constructions that are not really applicable for the Cryptography site.

Well, if it wasn't clear enough with the status-completed tag, I've edited the title to include $\TeX$ :P

Note that the answer with the easy to find MathJax crypto-notations can be found here

Normally, we do turn the setting on for a meta site when we do it for a main sites. I'm not sure why that didn't happen here, but as of a minute ago:
$$ MathJax \Rightarrow enabled $$

Wow, that was fast. Thanks!

Yep. Thought I'd start my week off with an easy win. ;-)
